# <img> tag not loading CodeSandbox.io

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have been trying add an image using the  tag on CodeSandbox.io. However, every time I try to add it, it doesn't show and just defaults to the alt tag (Displays logo).

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={require("./logo.svg")} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Image in codesandbox]

You can checkout my code and a live demo at this [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dont-show-logo-omfew?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codesandbox doesn't support directly importing images. Instead, you can either add them as [static uploads](https://codesandbox.io/docs/uploading) and reference their uploaded URL or import them as [React components](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs):

[image: Edit Import Images Codesandbox]

Comment: I had to convert my "logo.svg" file to "logo.png" otherwise logo.svg does not show into "Storage Management"; is that a normal behavior of codesandbox?

Comment: Not too sure, as I don't usually need images to work within my codesandboxes. That said, use the React component work-around to continue using SVGs. You can also use third party image hosters (like [imgur](https://imgur.com)) and use their hosted URLs instead.